# Fill excel or pdf with java rough guide

Tags: java, forms, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I have got some excel sheet and want to fill fields automaticly with data. I would like to be able to somehow tag the boxes where information can be entered. So I can then use some api (itext,pdfbox?) to fill these field without having to measure the pdf with a ruler and then paint into the right spaces. And it should be changable in the future.

What are the best apis and tool to use?

Which format should I use, xls, pdf, pdf with fdf or something better?

Project can invest 0 euros into buying tools.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Is it a PDF or Excel?  Where is the data coming from?  Are you generating the file?  What is the question about the formats for?

Comment: The excel is given, but converting that to pdf isn't hard, so I'm open in that respect. It's a basic table that has to be filled with numbers, really simple.

Comment: So you have an Excel file that you are converting a PDF?  Is that your question?

Comment: My question is, what apis and tools shall I use to fill a excel or pdf with data automatically.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a way to have a form filled out. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For modifying/creating:

- Excel: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)
- PDF:   [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

Comment: Just a headsup for whoever stumbles across this: iText unfortunately does not fall under the "0€ to buy" category any more... :-(